# how to organize inheritance in JavaScript in order to be able to place classes in different files?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, design-patterns

The problem is that it is convenient to place a class in a separate file, but I used to the only way of inheritance organization in JavaScript (something like the next example):

```
if (typeof app === 'undefined') {
    app = {};
}
app.Base = function() {}
app.Child = function() {}
app.Child.prototype = new app.Base();
```

and since I cannot split base and child classes between different files, cause at the time of calling `new app.Base();` `app.Base` may by not defined yet. So I'm forced to place all chain in one big file.

I would like don't bother with the order of files inclusion, cause for instance it is not very convenient when using Karma-runner to check the order of files inclusion in its config file, if it is possible at all with it.

Could anyone suggest something about this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just keep order in the included files, and it's not an issue.

Comment: @adeneo it is not very convenient when using Karma-runner, and may be it is not possible at all with it, I did not check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like Require.js. It allows you to split your files up into logical groups and maintain a nice dependency tree.

In this case you could split it up like

```
// This is base.js
define([], function(){
  var Base = function() {};
  return Base;
});

// This is child.js
define(['base'], function(Base) {
  var Child = function() {};
  Child.prototype = new Base();
  return Child;
});

// This is app.js
require( ['child'], function( Child ) {
  var myChild = new Child();
});
```

I really recommend looking into [require.js](http://requirejs.org/).

If you're in Node.js world you can simply use require and module.exports to simply maintain your dependencies.

ECMAScript 6 defines a new standard for modules which should make this all easier, this will take a while though until it is implemented in a sane usable way in every browser.

Comment: Require.js has the added benefit that you can use r.js to optimize the code later and create a compressed build.